# Maven profile dependency order

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, profile

I have something like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile> <id>a</id>
        <dependencies> <dependency> <x> </dependency> </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile> <id>b</id>
        <dependencies> <dependency> <y> </dependency> </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
<z>
</dependencies>
```

So profile a has a dependency x, profile b has dependency y. BOTH have dependency z. The issue is, maven puts dependency z before x or y. I need it the other way around. I need x/y to be override z.

How can I do this? My current workaround is to put the dependency of z in both the profiles like so:

```
<profiles>
    <profile> <id>a</id>
        <dependencies> 
        <dependency> <x> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <z> </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile> <id>b</id>
        <dependencies> 
        <dependency> <y> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <z> </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This works but seems like there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: What makes you think it does so (maven puts dependency z before x or y) ? Maven shall resolve dependencies in the same order they are declared in pom.xml.

Comment: I've tried it and confirmed it does put z before x.

Comment: What is the version of Maven?

Comment: 3.3.9 (checked within IntelliJ settings)

Comment: FROM Maven 2.0.0 Release notes. 
MNG-1412 / MNG-3111 introduced deterministic ordering of dependencies on the classpath. In the past, natural set ordering was used and this lead to odd results. The ordering is now preserved from your pom, with dependencies added by inheritence added last. In builds that had conflicting or duplicate dependencies, this may introduce a change to the output. In short, if you have weird issues with 2.0.9, take a look at the dependencies to see if you have conflicts somewhere.